# Adding delay after output reach n (i.e i count is 700). I tried using time.sleep but not sure how to add the condition for 700 output

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

what i am looking is the o/p line ....print "added %s to group %s" % (userUID, i).... such that if o./p come to n value then there should be delay interval . .

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# /usr/bin/python2.6

import time
for i in (inGroups):
tdn = "cn=" + i +",cn=groups,dc=apple,dc=com"
addToGroup = [
    (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'memberUid', userUID),

]
try:
    lod.modify_s(tdn, addToGroup)
    print "added %s to group %s" % (userUID, i)
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print "Fatal Error."
    if type(e.message) == dict:
        for (k, v) in e.message.iteritems():
            print "%s: %s\n" % (k, v)
        else:
            print "Error: %s\n" % e.message
    print addToGroup
    if i>700:
   time.sleep(10)
```

ALSO tried

```
if addToGroup.count(10):
            time.sleep(10)
                print("Wait for 10 sec,addToGroup")
```

Comment: sleep() should be correct. It's a little difficult however to figure out your issue due to identation issues. Is this how your code is in your editor?

Comment: This should be working. Perhaps check the error message given, maybe a value that is not included in this snippet is causing the error. Try checking for it. If you can't figure out where the error might be from, check the error traceback given in most code editors

Comment: Now here 'i' takes value fro starting , what i am looking is the o/p   line ....print "added %s to group %s" % (userUID, i).... such that if o./p come to n value then there should be delay interval .

Comment: @PythonProgrammer any luck